# Qt5 mouseDoubleClick event management

Tags: qt4, qt5, porting, double-click

According to Qt5 [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) (search for mouseDoubleClickEvent) :

> mouseDoubleClickEvent() is called when the user double-clicks in the
>   widget. If the user double-clicks, the widget receives **a mouse press
>   event, a mouse release event, (a mouse click event,) a second mouse
>   press, this event and finally a second mouse release event**. (Some
>   mouse move events may also be received if the mouse is not held steady
>   during this operation.) It is not possible to distinguish a click from
>   a double-click until the second click arrives. (This is one reason why
>   most GUI books recommend that double-clicks be an extension of
>   single-clicks, rather than trigger a different action.)

Which is different from Qt4 [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html) (search for mouseDoubleClickEvent):

> mouseDoubleClickEvent() is called when the user double-clicks in the
>   widget. If the user double-clicks, the widget receives **a mouse press
>   event, a mouse release event and finally this event instead of a
>   second mouse press event.** (Some mouse move events may also be received
>   if the mouse is not held steady during this operation.) It is not
>   possible to distinguish a click from a double-click until the second
>   click arrives. (This is one reason why most GUI books recommend that
>   double-clicks be an extension of single-clicks, rather than trigger a
>   different action.)

I'm currently porting an application from Qt4 to Qt5, so I need to be able to "wait" for the mouseDoubleClickEvent when receiving the secound mousePressEvent.

Even tough I can fix this what a timer, is there something i am missing here ? This new pattern does not seem very practical, how could i avoid this ? can I remove the second mouse press somehow ?

Comment: Can you provide a reference to that text in the Qt5 docs?  I see the sequence press/release/double click/release (Linux + Qt 5.10.0).

Comment: I've updated my answer. Which widget are you testing with ?

Comment: I think it may just be the documentation that's incorrect in this case.  I'm testing with a raw `QWidget` and event filter.

Comment: I have indeed the same behavior with a raw QOpenGLWindow (my window is based on it). I will debug and let you know.

Comment: Nevermind. I see the same as you with a QWidget but i see the same as the Qt5 doc with a QWindow.

Comment: I've found a Qt Issue that seem to indicate that this was fixed only for widget and not for window: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-25831

In any case there is a flag on the second mouse press event that allows me to manage this cleanly.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#MouseEventFlag-enum